# Convert hours in decimal to duration and add to another column

Tags: r, lubridate, huawei-mobile-services

I have one column that is a time of day (start_time), and a second that is a duration in hours that's in decimal format (duration_hours).

I'd like to convert the duration into HH:MM and then add it to the start time to create a new variable (end_time) that's time of day when the experiment stopped.

1. How do I convert the decimal to HH:MM?  I tried as_duration but it made it into seconds
2. How do I then add that duration to the start time to make another time of day?

Thank you!

```r
library(tidyr)
library(hms)

data <- tribble(
  ~id, ~start_time, ~duration_hours,
  #--/---/---
  "a","6:30:00",6.47,
  "b", "17:05:30",5.30
)

data$start_time<-hms::as_hms(data$start_time)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Do you want `hms::hms(seconds_to_period(data$duration_hours * 3600))`

Comment: YES!  That converted it to the period!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hms` is just the number of seconds, so you may do

```
transform(data, end_time=as_hms(as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), start_time)) + duration_hours*60^2))
#   id start_time duration_hours end_time
# 1  a   06:30:00           6.47 12:58:12
# 2  b   17:05:30           5.30 22:23:30
```

Or using `strftime`

```
transform(data, end_time=strftime(as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), start_time)) + duration_hours*60^2, "%T"))
#   id start_time duration_hours end_time
# 1  a    6:30:00           6.47 12:58:12
# 2  b   17:05:30           5.30 22:23:30
```

Comment: That almost has me there - Does the start time need to be in a particular format?  
Here's the output I'm getting:
https://imgur.com/a/qVrZqJv

Comment: @jpryan28 Weird, can't reproduce though. Could you post `str(your_data)`, just relevant columns? What actually should happen if there's a day swith at end time?

Comment: start time:   'hms' num [1:10177] NA NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"


duration:  num [1:10177] 3.23 4.12 6.67 6.43 2.48 ...
 - attr(*, "label")= chr "Ischemic Time (hours)"


If there's a day switch at end time, I'd like it to just go to the next day.  e.g. 22:00 + 4.00 = 02:00

Comment: @jpryan28 I see, your original data appears to be in `hms`format, whereas your sample data is `hms`. You should be specific there. I added another solution which yields `"character"`format though. No clue why you get milliseconds, even if I set `options(digits.secs=3)`I get no milliseconds,..

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(lubridate)
hms::hms(seconds_to_period(data$duration_hours * 3600))
```